# Solving the Double-Choco Puzzle: Matching Sub-Matrices with Rotation and Mirroring

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-programming

I'm working on implementing a solver for [Double-Choco](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/double_choco/) puzzle which published by Nikoli magazine. starting by representing the board cells as matrix containing cells with values 1 or 0, where 1 represents gray cells and 0 represents white cells.

For instance:

```
[
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
]
```

My goal is to identify matching sub-arrays from each color that have the same shape and size, considering the possibility of rotation or mirroring.

- I'm wondering if LP-solvers or other tools could be effective for
  solving this problem?

  Or if I should implement a solution myself.
- Could anyone provide guidance on what algorithms might be suitable
  for achieving this goal?

Thank you in advance for any insights or advice!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide a self-contained statement of the problem.  What is your question?  Is your question how to find a solver for Double-Choco?  If so, please describe Double-Choco and explain what is meant by a solver.  Is your question how to identifying matching sub-arrays?  If so, please explain what that means.  What is a matching sub-array?  Can you formulate the problem mathematically?  What does it mean to "consider the possibility of rotation or mirroring"?